# this.options is not defined inside public method Jquery Widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I facing problem in in identifying whats wrong with ,y code in Jquery widget . I trying to get this.options inside a public method . but i am getting error

> "Type error: this.option is not defined"

" at **bindOption**  at exactly at

> self.find(this.options.selectionGroup + " " +
>   this.options.selectionElement)

this.options is looks to me out of this scope , where i am going here ??

my code goes like below :

```
 _create: function() {

                var self = this;
                var $el = this.element;

                $el.find(this.options.optionsGroup + " .option").on('click',
                        this.bindOption);
                this._hideToggle($el, this.options.optionsGroup, 'show');


            },
            bindOption: function() {

                $val = $(this).html();
                var self=this;
                $data = $(this).attr('data-option');
                 self.find(this.options.selectionGroup + " " + this.options.selectionElement)
                        .attr('data-selection', $data).html($val);

            }
```

**Solved :**

was using self.find in the bindOption , but it need to apply find() on element  so I changed

`self.find(this.options.selectionGroup + " " + this.options.selectionElement)`  to

```
 self.element.find(this.options.selectionGroup + " " + this.options.selectionElement)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
$el.find(this.options.optionsGroup + " .option").on('click', $.proxy(this.bindOption, this));
```

Since `bindOption` is added as a callback to an event, `this` inside `bindOption` does not point to the widget, it refers the dom element which triggered the event. You can fix it by passing a custom execution context to the callback handler using [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Comment: thank you very much for your response . actually the problem was im applying find() on 'self' but it should be on 'self.element' .Your proxy suggestion helped me to improve knowledge on Proxy thank you very much .